# Taking a screenshot, analyzing it, then deleting it

Tags: c++, windows

I've been trying to code an auto clicker for a simple game online (a php coded one), but I've had trouble analyzing the colors on-screen. (English isn't my first language, sorry!) I've already done a bit of C++ in university, but only for science-oriented simple console programs. (Edit: I'm working on windows!! forgot to mention)

I've already tried the getpixel function, but since my chrome window is zoomed out at 80% to get the full game in frame, it seems I'm having some DPI related issues, but looking into this made my head dizzy.

After watching a Codebullet video, I thought a better approach to this would be to take a screenshot of the problematic area, analyze it to see if the condition is filled, then delete the screenshot. The problem is, I have no idea how I could achieve this and Google didn't help much this time :\

My code is extremely messy so I can't show it right now, but it's basically just a:

-click there

-click there after 5 seconds

-click there if this pixel is this color

-repeat

Is there an easy answer to this? I'd be really thankful if there is. Have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to save the screen shot if you don't want to:

Pass the target window handle to GetDC(), t will return the the device context of the window.

Pass the device context to CreateCompatibleDC() to create a compatible DC.

Use CreateCompatibleBitmap(), passing in the DC and the size of the window.  This returns a handle to a bitmap

Use SelectObject() to select the bitmap

Use BitBlt() to do a bitblock transfer of the selected pixels from the regular DC into the compatible DC using the SRCCOPY raster operation code to do a normal copy.

Create a BITMAP object.  Use GetObject() and pass the handle to the bitmap you created.

Create a BITMAPINFOHEADER and define the member vars.  Create an array of unsigned chars big enough to fit all the pixels from your bitmap.

Use GetDIBits() passing in the handle to the compatible bitmap, the bitmap header and a pointer to the pixel array.  This loads the pixels from the bitmap into the pixel array.

Now parse all that juicy pixel data, search for the colors you're looking for and test the results against your conditionals to decide what to do next.

Don't forget to delete objects and release memory & device contexts.

I believe this is the tutorial I followed where I learned this, courtesy of MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/capturing-an-image

Comment: Ok, right now I think I'm not experienced enough to understand everything, but surely tomorrow with a bit more googling, it could do the trick! Thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: I added a link to a tutorial, I believe that's the one I used in the past